# Significantly different histograms

Tags: histogram

I need to test whether two histograms are significantly different from each other in terms of mean and variance. Both histograms only consist of two bars. (When) should I use two sample Kolomgorov-Smirnov or (Pearson's) Chi Square? How big should the sample size be for each? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Regarding chi square, I am also unsure whether to test for goodness of fit or for homogeneity. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: KS is for continuous data, while CS works for categorical data. Therefore for comparing two histograms CS works better. However, it also needs sufficient sample size of at least 5 observations per cell.